# Join my cart table to my customer table

Tags: php, sql

I want to join my cart table to my customer table, so I can add the product_quantity table to prevent users from inputting higher number than the quantity of the product. For me, this can be a way to make this work. Thanks

This is my `add_cart.php`

```
<?php

        include('session.php');
        if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
            $id=$_POST['id'];
            $qty=$_POST['qty'];


            $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");


            if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
                echo "Product already on your cart!";

    }

            else{
                mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
            }

        }

    ?>
```

This is my product table.

[PRODUCT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuFFa.jpg)

This is my cart table.

[Cart Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd58q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use  `INNER JOIN` to link two table by `productid`

```
select * from cart 
INNER JOIN product ON cart.productid = product.productid
where cart.productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
from cart 
inner join product 
on (cart.productid = product.productid)
where cart.productid = '$id' 
and cart.userid = '".$_SESSION['id']."'
```